# FFmpeg producing a flickering video from images

Tags: java, maven, video, ffmpeg

So I'm trying to make a video of a fractal rotating through some values, much like seen [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Julia_set#/media/File:JSr07885.gif).

I generate the frames (1000 of them) using a different program written in Java that works just fine, so for the purposes of this scenario assume that all the images are in the target folder and also in numerical order as they need to appear in the video.

I found the following code on the web to stitch images into a video, and I haven't the faintest idea how it works, and when I run it, all of the images are indeed stitched into a video and placed on the desktop, but the video appears to have one specific frame just jump in at random positions. I'm not totally sure which one, but its one of the earlier frames, somewhere between 1 and 200 of the 1000.

I've also tested making two half videos, one using the first 500 frames, and the other using the second 500 frames. The first video (1 -> 500) has flickering, and the second video (501 -> 1000) appears not to have flickering to my observations.

I am seeking help in fixing the flickering behavior, and I will upload the video file to google drive later if asked. The Images are all 1920x1080, and in proper numerical order.

Thanks in advance!

```
import static org.bytedeco.javacpp.opencv_imgcodecs.*;
import java.io.File; 
import org.bytedeco.javacpp.avcodec;
import org.bytedeco.javacv.FFmpegFrameRecorder;
import org.bytedeco.javacv.OpenCVFrameConverter;
public class ImageToMovie{
    public static void main(String []args){
        String imgPath="C:\\Users\\John\\Images";
        String vidPath="C:\\Users\\John\\Desktop\\video.mp4";
        String[] links=new String[new File(imgPath).listFiles().length];
        File f=new File(imgPath);
        File[] f2=f.listFiles();
        for(int i=0;i<f2.length;i++) {
            links[i]=f2[i].getAbsolutePath();
        }
        convertJPGtoMovie(links, vidPath);
        System.out.println("Video has been created at "+vidPath);
    }
    public static void convertJPGtoMovie(String[] links, String vidPath){
        OpenCVFrameConverter.ToIplImage grabberConverter = new OpenCVFrameConverter.ToIplImage();
        FFmpegFrameRecorder recorder = new FFmpegFrameRecorder(vidPath,1920,1080); 
        try {
            recorder.setFrameRate(50);
            recorder.setVideoCodec(avcodec.AV_CODEC_ID_MPEG4);
            recorder.setVideoBitrate(100000);
            recorder.setFormat("mp4");
            recorder.setVideoQuality(0);
            recorder.start();
            for (int i=0;i<links.length;i++){
                recorder.record(grabberConverter.convert(cvLoadImage(links[i])));
            }
            recorder.stop();
        }
        catch (org.bytedeco.javacv.FrameRecorder.Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You just need to sort your `File` array to be in the correct order.

The video will be generated using whatever order the files array is in. So make sure that the files are sorted numerically, because if they are not then you are likely to have files ordered like `1, 10, 100, 101, 102` instead of `1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6`.

The reason you don’t notice the flickering between image 500 and 1000 is that all files are 3 numbers long so you will not see that effect in the larger numbers.

Comment: Sorifiend, You've saved my life. Truly grateful. I didn't realize they were in the wrong order because File explorer in windows assumed I wanted it from 1 -> 1000, but the programs that stitches them doesn't treat "image 1" as "image 0001" like I expected it to. Probably never would have thought of that.